# Can't get mysql_fetch_rows to cooperate

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I'm trying to retrieve rows from a mysql table based on variables input by the user. Basically if use wants to search for "bob dilan" $fname and $lname would search and display all rows where this takes place, my connection to the user is fine as my $mysql_num_fields is working perfectly. Currently nothing works inside of my mysql_fetch_rows while loop, not even the echos, but there are no errors. I have even tried using the like operator instead of = to no avail.

PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  ".$tbl_name." 
WHERE fname='".$fname."' 
and lname='".$lname."' 
and city='".$city."'
and phone='".$pohne."'
and interest_inet='".$internet."'
and interest_tv='".$television."'
and interest_voice='".$voice."'
and submission_ip='".$ip."'
and inquiry_handled='".$handled."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
$i = 0;

while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result))
{
    $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);   
    echo "<th>".$meta->name."</th>";
    $i++;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo '<tr>';

foreach($row as $item)
{
    echo "<td>".$item."</td>";
}

echo '</tr>';
echo $row;
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I understand thanks, also, love the name.

Comment: Actually, your avatar kinda looks like my eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already iterating through the resultset once, which causes the pointer to advance to the end of it.

Complete all of your work in a single loop, or fetch the entire resultset into an array, and iterate it twice.

Other than that, you [**shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I think im missing what you mean, there are two seperate while loops, the first displays column names and the second SHOULD echo rows in which $sql is true, but its not. hence the problem

Comment: @JohnDoe: Once a query is run, a resultset is returned. A pointer in memory is set on the first item. When you loop, the resultset pointer automatically advances (That's why you don't need to increment a variable or anything when looping). After you're done, there's nothing to place that pointer back at the first item, so further calls to `mysql_fetch_*` will return nothing.

Comment: Real quick question that is bothering me a bit.  if i had a value for fname, but nothing was posted over for the other variables, it should still echo results frop the table whereever fname matches correct?

Comment: @JohnDoe: No. Since you're applying `AND` between each condition, it will only work if all of the other fields are empty. You are perhaps looking for `OR`.

Comment: I considered OR, but OR just displays the entire table

Comment: @JohnDoe: In that case, you want to build your query in a way so that only included terms are placed in the query. I've seen scripts like those running around here on [so], and if you can't find any, you can always try to implement it yourself.

Comment: I had an idea for what, but it was 72 functions long, but this way is clearly not going to work for me. guess i ought to buckle down and get to it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to solve this problem is to use [mysql_data_seek](http://www.php.net/mysql-data-seek)

```
while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result))
{
    $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);   
    echo "<th>".$meta->name."</th>";
    $i++;
}

mysql_data_seek($result);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
```